# Can I purchase an MIT 6.270 kit anywhere? If not are there alternatives?

Tags: robotics, kits

When I was in High School I used to work with the [MIT 6.270 Robotics Kits](http://spacecats.mit.edu/~6.270/about/) in a Robotics class I both took and then later was a TA for. I loved those kits, they had an embedded controller you could program in C-code, and you built the robots using legos.

[image: 6.270 Board]

[image]

Is there anywhere I can purchase one of these boards? I see that I get one if I [become a Gold supporter of the 6.270](http://spacecats.mit.edu/sponsors/info.shtml) but I don't have a spare $10,000 at the moment...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just buy a LEGO RCX or NXT set? They're exactly what you're searching...

http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms

Comment: I was unaware I could program a Mindstorms kit in C. I thought it had to be their proprietary language... or Java. Last time I used a Mindstorms kit was 10 years ago though...

Comment: RCX had its own linux distribution, with toolchain and whatever. LegOS was its name, IIRC. Something similar exists for NXT, but I have not yet tried it: http://lejos-osek.sourceforge.net/